# Multiple Vertex Buffers OpenGL c++

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to draw 2 Vertex Buffers but it only draws the second one. I am using OpenGL 4.6 and the COMPAT profile. The code:

```
    float buffer[] =
    {
        0.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,1.0f
    };
    float buffera[] =
    {
        0.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,0.0f,
        1.0f,-1.0f
    };
    unsigned int id;
    glGenBuffers(1, &id);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    unsigned int ida;
    glGenBuffers(1, &ida);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffera, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    unsigned int indices[]
    {
        0,1,2
    };
```

And then the draw calls:

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) is called, the the buffer which is currently bound to the target `ARRAY_BUFFER` is associated to the attribute. It is not sufficient to bind the buffer object. You have to do the vertex specification before drawing the object:

```cpp
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

I recommend to use a [Vertex Array Object](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object). The VAO is used to store the vertex specification.

```cpp
unsigned int vao1;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao1);
glBindVertexArray(vao1);

unsigned int id;
glGenBuffers(1, &id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);

unsigned int vao2;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao2);
glBindVertexArray(vao2);

unsigned int ida;
glGenBuffers(1, &ida);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffera, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
```

```cpp
glBindVertexArray(vao1);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
glBindVertexArray(vao2);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are not using a VAO, only binding the buffer is not enough. The command which establishes from which buffer a draw command reads is `glVertexAttribPointer`. You have to move this command into to the draw commands (and since they aren't doing anthing, remove them from the initialization.

The code should be something like:

Init:

```
unsigned int id;
glGenBuffers(1, &id);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffer, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

unsigned int ida;
glGenBuffers(1, &ida);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), buffera, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Drawing:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, id);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ida);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), (const void*)8);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 3, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indices);
```